# Strange delay with touchesBegan in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I recently updated to iOS10 and Swift 3. And know, whenever I run my app on an iOS10 device (iPhone6s in my case) there is a randomly occurring delay of the touchesBegan function. Sometimes this is accompanied with the following error message:

> "Gesture: Failed to receive system gesture state notification before
>   next touch"

Interestingly my older iPhone5s running iOS9 does not reproduce this problem.

Comment: I have experienced some 3D touch related issues in iOS10. Out of curiosity, if you disable 3D touch in General->Accessibility on your device does the problem disappear?

Comment: @Columbo Yes actually! I just turned off 3d touch, and the problem stopped. Thing is, it only really happened on the lower left side of the screen, so I simply assumed that my device was faulty. Hopefully this is only a software issue.

Comment: Probably the best option you have is to file a bug report to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Usually strange UI delays on iOS have to do with threads. UI related methods on iOS and Mac are all meant to be called from the main thread only. Because the APIs are becoming highly asynchronous, with many methods taking a block callback, it's easy to accidentally do something UI-related from a background thread.

Make sure that any UI-related activity, whether it's updating an image, a text field, reloading a table view, etc, is always done from the main thread. If you're doing UI stuff within a block, you can wrap the UI parts inside dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ...).

I'm my experience, an inadvertent background-thread call to one of these methods can have an effect of "poisoning the well," causing subsequent weirdness such as the delayed touch events you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I simulate a touch and hold to steer a car right and left. Here was what fixed it for me.

**Changing the follow from:**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node: SKNode = atPoint(location)

        if node == self.player1CarRight {
                self.player1CarRotateRightTouching = true
        }
    }
}
```

**To:**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

    if player1CarRight.contains(touchLocation) {
        self.player1CarRotateRightTouching = true;
    }
}
```

Same change in touchesEnded:

```
override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
       let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
       let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self)

        if player1CarRight.contains(touchLocation) {
            self.player1CarRotateRightTouching = false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this behavior today, but perhaps for a different reason.  My scenario involved having a UITapGestureRecognizer on a superview of the view that implements touchesBegan.  Since the UITapGestureRecognizer was recognizing a tap, and because the default for cancelsTouchesInView on the tap recognizer is YES, once the recognizer recognized the touch, the views don't get any of the touch callbacks.  However, if I touch and hold, the UITapGestureRecognizer fails to recognize the touch, and then the views get the callbacks.  This results in what looks like a delayed call to touchesBegan.

I also noticed as part of this investigation that UIButtons get special treatment here.  If a UITapGestureRecognizer is in play, it will not consider touches on UIButtons.